Applying a nested filter while configuring a Search component
I have a quick question on how to apply a nested filter in the search component.
For instance, I have a Product Entity and a Taxonomy A, which has only two values: True and False, and is related solely to the Product Entity.
On the Product Entity details page, I have an Assets tab that currently shows only the assets tagged with the Product. In addition to these, I also want to display the assets that are tagged as True under Taxonomy A.

you mentioned Taxonomy is related solely to Product..But you would like to display assets tagged with Taxonomy..Its little bit unclear..Can you please add some more description and images of the relations if possible.
